# Text and background-color overlay on image

Tags: html, css, image, overlay, figure

I'm trying to create a solid-color overlay that exactly matches the size of an image, and display text on that overlay.  I'd like to do this with HTML and CSS only, if possible.

[image: image without overlay]

[image: image with overlay and text]

The image may be of any size, and will be sized to fit and centered within its parent container. Something like this (which does not work):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="img-overlay">
  <img src="file.jpg">
  <div class="overlay">Text will flow...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img-overlay img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

I thought that HTML5's `<figure>` tag might help here, but haven't had much success on that front. The following keeps the caption width pegged to the image width, but when I try to remove it from the document flow and position it over the image, it ends up to the left of the image due to the image centering via `margin: 0 auto;`.

```
<figure>
  <img src="file.jpg">
  <figcaption>Text will flow...</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made an example for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/kb3Kf/2/

The main thing that was missing was that you gave the text an Absolute position but didn't give the wrapper a Relative one, like so:

```
.img-overlay
{
    position: relative;
}
```

It's really simple, you can take it to many directions. Tell me if that's what you wanted.

Comment: you're both right -- forgot to set parent element's position. duh.

Answer (score 2):

You are just missing setting the position of the parent img-overlay element. When something has a position of "absolute", that refers to where it is in relation to its parent. The parent needs to have positioning.

```
.img-overlay {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;

}

.img-overlay img {
width:100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

}
```