# Adding an image on another image as a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a gallery.

The gallery is divided in to 4 a row grid. You can select images and with Javascript I place the images in the grid.

This is my code:

```js
let column1 = document.getElementsByClassName('column1')[0];
let column2 = document.getElementsByClassName('column2')[0];
let column3 = document.getElementsByClassName('column3')[0];
let column4 = document.getElementsByClassName('column4')[0];



let column = 1;

document.getElementById('picField').onchange = function (evt) {
    let tgt = evt.target || window.event.srcElement,
        files = tgt.files;
    for (let x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
        // FileReader support
        if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
            let fr = new FileReader();
            fr.readAsDataURL(files[x]);
            fr.onload = function () {

                let img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = fr.result;

                let removeButton = document.createElement("img");
                removeButton.src = "remove.png";

                if (column == 1) {
                    column1.appendChild(img);
                    column++;
                } else if (column == 2) {
                    column2.appendChild(img);
                    column++;
                } else if (column == 3) {
                    column3.appendChild(img);
                    column++;
                } else if (column == 4) {
                    column4.appendChild(img);
                    column = 1;
                }
            }

        }

        // Not supported
        else {
            // fallback -- perhaps submit the input to an iframe and temporarily store
            // them on the server until the user's session ends.
        }
    }


}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
    margin: 30px 60px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-style: ridge;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .column {
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="load">
        <input type="file" name="picField" id="picField" size="24" onchange="preview_2(this);" alt="" accept="image/*"
            multiple />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column column1">
        </div>
        <div class="column column2">
        </div>
        <div class="column column3">
        </div>
        <div class="column column4">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="/app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Now I added an extra image:

```js
let removeButton = document.createElement("img");
                removeButton.src = "remove.png";
```

[This removeButton is just a simple 24px red cross](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/close_579006#term=cross&page=1&position=18). I would like to add this removeButton to the right corner of every image. When an user clicked the removeButton the image has to be deleted from the gallery.

The Javascript implementation is not that hard I suppose. When the image and the removeButton share the same parent. I can select the parent and remove it.

But i failed to get the layout right. I tried to make the image relative and the removeButton absolute. But then the removeButton is displayed absolute to the body, not to the image.

First I added the removeButton as an child of the image. Then I wrap the elements in a div, but noting worked. [This is what i have in mind.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSKcg.png)

Anybody who can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `<button>` instead, you can assign it an image and style it accordingly. Having both been images is not a good idea, and is not a good idea in general to have something that is clearly a `<button>` being an `<img>` for accessibility. I think going that route you may get it to work. I can think of an example based on your code if you don't get around the idea.

*Edited with a little example of what I'm thinking*

```
let removeButton = document.createElement("button");
removeButton.classList.add("button-delete");
removeButton.innerHTML = "X";

if (column == 1) {
    column1.appendChild(img);
    // You will have to append this button to each column manually to each column number
    column1.appendChild(removeButton);
    column++;
```

Also, you will have to add the `click` function to the button, which in your case, will have to delete the img element and the button itself... but bear in mind... the way you're doing this is a little hard-coded, thing, when you delete an image, you'll also should say, well, the number of columns should decrese, but if you already had an image in this gallery, and remove the one in the middle, this won't look good.

This is already another issue in here, but I would like to suggest you to do this less forced, like, try not to use to many `if`s if you can, first, try to put the images to wrap automatically, the first thing to come in my mind is to use `flex` to just wrap them as they fit the gallery div, this way you should only remove the images and the wraping will be fixed by itself and you don't have to keep count of the columns and that sort of things.

Sorry if I was not clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

[I found this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175422/text-and-background-color-overlay-on-image) I tried to create one img with overlay in an separate file and it worked.

Than i implemented this in my project and now it worked fine:

```js
let column1 = document.getElementsByClassName('column1')[0];
let column2 = document.getElementsByClassName('column2')[0];
let column3 = document.getElementsByClassName('column3')[0];
let column4 = document.getElementsByClassName('column4')[0];



let column = 1;

document.getElementById('picField').onchange = function (evt) {
    let tgt = evt.target || window.event.srcElement,
        files = tgt.files;
    for (let x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
        // FileReader support
        if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
            let fr = new FileReader();
            fr.readAsDataURL(files[x]);
            fr.onload = function () {

                let containerDiv = document.createElement("div");
                containerDiv.setAttribute("class", "img-overlay");

                let img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = fr.result;

                let removeButton = document.createElement("button");
                removeButton.setAttribute("class", "overlay");

                let removeImage = document.createElement("img");
                removeImage.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/579/579006.svg";

                removeButton.appendChild(removeImage);

                containerDiv.appendChild(img);
                containerDiv.appendChild(removeButton);

                if (column == 1) {
                    column1.appendChild(containerDiv);
                    column++;
                } else if (column == 2) {
                    column2.appendChild(containerDiv);
                    column++;
                } else if (column == 3) {
                    column3.appendChild(containerDiv);
                    column++;
                } else if (column == 4) {
                    column4.appendChild(containerDiv);
                    column = 1;
                }
            }

        }

        // Not supported
        else {
            // fallback -- perhaps submit the input to an iframe and temporarily store
            // them on the server until the user's session ends.
        }
    }


}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
    margin: 30px 60px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-style: ridge;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.img-overlay {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;

}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    top: 6px;
    right: 3px;
}


.column img {
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .column {
        min-width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        min-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="load">
        <input type="file" name="picField" id="picField" size="24" onchange="preview_2(this);" alt="" accept="image/*"
            multiple />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column column1">
        </div>
        <div class="column column2">
        </div>
        <div class="column column3">
        </div>
        <div class="column column4">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="/app.js"></script>

</html>
```

I added an position to the img and that was wrong. Now it works fine and i can start to implementing the delete function.